# Chat.SE is down?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I know this isn't a question, but for the time being, [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is giving a 500 Internal Server Error, and none of the chatrooms seem to be working correctly. [It doesn't appear to be just me, either.](http://isup.me/chat.stackexchange.com) Is this due to regularly-scheduled downtime, or is there a problem with chat?

Comment: Normally I'd ask about this in chat, but obviously that isn't going to happen. As an aside, http://chat.stackoverflow.com is still up.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a temporary bad DNS issue; more details are available in the official answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175163/167701